# OnModelCreating Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-core

This code is in `MVC`, I need to do something like this but in `ASP.net Core`, using `Entity Framework Core`, or with `DataAnnotations` (I've changed the parameter already from `DbModelBuilder(MVC Entity Framework)` to `ModelBuilder(Entity Framework Core)`)

```
 protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<OneToManyCascadeDeleteConvention>(); //error: Conventions is not recognized
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
            modelBuilder.Entity<tbl_Line>()
                .HasMany(d => d.tbl_Policy)
                .WithRequired(c => c.tbl_Line) //error WithRequired not recognized
                .HasForeignKey(c => c.int_lineID);
        }
```

There are some errors when I'm trying to use it in `Entity Framework Core`:

1-`'ModelBuilder' does not contain a definition for 'Conventions' and no extension method 'Conventions' accepting a first argument of type 'ModelBuilder' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

2-`'CollectionNavigationBuilder<tbl_Line, tbl_Policy>' does not contain a definition for 'WithRequired' and no extension method 'WithRequired' accepting a first argument of type 'CollectionNavigationBuilder<tbl_Line, tbl_Policy>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

Comment: A good starting point - [EF Core vs. EF6.x](https://docs.efproject.net/en/latest/efcore-vs-ef6/index.html#)

Comment: @IvanStoev page not found. Even I want to use configurations to add a map in my ef core context file. Writing the mappings in the same file looks messy. Is there a way, or need to add it the same way AlexGh has done it.

Comment: @nakulchawla09 The recent documentation is [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/efcore-and-ef6/). Shortly, there is still no support for Conventions and/or Configurations in EF Core like in EF6 (AFAIK there are plans to be added, but I don't know when), so for now you are stuck with `modelBuilder`.

Comment: Thanks @IvanStoev. Will use the ModelBuilder for now then. Sigh...

Answer (score 2):

Until there is support for *ModelBuilder.Configurations* I emulate the older *Entity Framework* construction with extension methods:

```
public static EntityTypeBuilder<Project> Map(this EntityTypeBuilder<Project> cfg)
{
    cfg.ToTable("sql_Projects");

    // Primary Key
    cfg.HasKey(p => p.Id);

    cfg.Property(p => p.Id)
        .IsRequired()
        .HasColumnName("ProjectId");

    return cfg;
}
```

and then call it from *OnModelCreating* like this...

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Project>().Map();
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
}
```

It is a bit clumsy, but cleaner, I think, than trying to configure dozens of entities within the main DbContext.

Comment: This method doesn't seem to exist.

Comment: Which method are you referring to?

Comment: @Nathan McKaskle: A few years late but I assume you mean [`ToTable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.relationalentitytypebuilderextensions.totable?view=efcore-8.0). You need to add the [`Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational/) package. I just had the same issue with [`ToView`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.relationalentitytypebuilderextensions.toview?view=efcore-8.0). *Just adding this note here so others can save some time.*

Comment: Wow I vaguely remember C#